# ArcMap not displaying bottom of windows

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, display, arcgis-10.7, arcgis-10.8

I recently installed ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.2 (Release V.:10.8.2/Product V.:10.9.1.28388) and some of the windows do not display complete information. I don't know why and I don't know how to fix it.

I had a 10.7 version of ArcMap prior to installing 10.8 with this same problem. That is why I updated it to 10.8, hoping to fix the problem. The problem happened after I renewed the license.

How can I fix this?

For example, in the symbology window, even when I scroll down to the bottom, I cannot see all the buttons.

[image]

Or the clip options in the data frame properties:

[image]

Or even the info in the layer properties:

[image]

I did uninstall and install it again, but nothing changed.

**Any ideas?**

I tried the suggestion from @BERA and @M92_. I changed the DPI on Windows display and ArcMap.exe, but it did not fix the problem. It is less blurry, but I still have the display/scroll problem. Btw, I am using the Windows 11 Pro, type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor.

[image]
[image]

I tried the suggestion from @johns. I changed the display height from 286 to 1000 mm in the Advanced Map Settings. I can see more info on the layer properties window, but symbology did not change.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, Bera. Thank you for your comment. The dpi of the windows display was 125%. I returned it to 150% (recommended), but it did not solve my problem. I added another picture in my post after changing the dpi.

Comment: Can you install 10.9 or at least get 10.8.1?  Did you have an older version of ArcMap prior to installing 10.8 that worked fine?

Comment: There is a monitor settings option in the Advanced Map Settings utility here: C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.8\Utilities.

Comment: Hi, Johns. I am using the 10.8.2 version. Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, it did not work. I changed the monitor settings and increased the display height from 286 to 1000 mm. I can see more info on the layer properties window, but symbology did not change. I'll update the question to show you.

Comment: I had 10.7 installed before, but with this same problem. That is why I updated it to 10.8. Hoping it would fix it. The scroll/display problem happened after I renew the license.

Comment: Try asking ESRI support

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

1. Open the folder of your ArcMap install location
2. Select "ArcMap.exe", right click and click on "Properties"
3. From the "Compatibility" tab, choose "Change high DPI settings"
4. Check "Override high DPI scaling behavior" and click "OK"

[image]

This will make your ArcMap display much clearer (with less or no blur) and it'll probably fix your display/scroll problem as well.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your answer. I tried it, but it did not fix the problem. I restarted the computer, did not help. It is less blurry, but the display/scroll problem is still here. I uploaded the screenshot in the question. Would you have any other suggestions?